# App Engine PHP upload error

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I have a PHP app engine instance that has already been whitelisted. I am an "Owner" on that application. I have a running a local instance of Wordpress. I followed all of the steps in the documentation. However, when I try to push the application to production, I get the following:

06:27 PM Scanning files on local disk.
06:27 PM Scanned 500 files.
06:27 PM Scanned 1000 files.
Error 400: --- begin server output ---
Invalid runtime or the current user is not authorized to use it.
--- end server output ---

My YAML looks exactly like the one in the documentation (with the proper application ID of course). Locally, Wordpress works perfectly fine. Any thoughts as to why this is happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Found the answer. Apparently (not clear in their documentation) is that users also need to get whitelisted. Even though my App Engine instance was, the user was not. Google just confirmed they whitelisted my user account, so now it works.

Comment: How did you request for whitelisting?

Comment: gaeforphp.appspot.com

Comment: How long did it take for your app to be whitelisted?